# Ajax request returning 403 error

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, ubuntu

I am running a site on my VirtualBox Ubuntu. Trying to make an Ajax request I get a 403 error. Now I know Linux is rather weird with permissions. My Linux adept friend tried and failed to help me over about an hour. Code is below. Let me know if more information is needed.

JS:

```
 function emailValidation (email) {
    $.post('../../application/controller/account/emailValidation', 
         {'email':email}
    );
 }
```

PHP:

```
   function emailValidation ($email) {
        $this->load->helper('email');
        if (valid_email('$email')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

ERROR: "You don't have permission to access /application/controller/account/emailValidation on this server."

Comment: So did you check the permission on all the folders from `/application` to the `emailValidation` file?  Notice that the directories must be (at least) executable, but readable is fine, and that `emailValidation` must be readable.  Note these are all by the user id of the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

The path in my Ajax was incorrect. It needed to be /account/emailValidation. It's a noob mistake. Thanks for helping though.